# cython multiple return

Tags: python, cython

I want to wrap this simple function:

```
       double foo(int a, int* b)
       {
          double div = ((double) a) / ((double) *b);
          *b = a + (*b);
          return div;
        }
```

what i'm trying to do is this:

```
      cdef pyfoo(int c, int d):
         res = foo(c, &d);
         return (res, d)
```

I want to return a list of values,  but using cdef it does not work
it gives me the erroe: AttributeError no attribute pyfoo
If instead of cdef i use def or cpdef it works.

Is there some way in cython to do this using cdef?

Answer (score 6):

`cdef` functions can't be accessed by Python code. That's why they're fast: calling functions from Python is always slow.

The solution is using `cpdef` instead, so that it's both accessible from Python and fast when called from C. Or, don't call it from Python code.

Comment: Thank you,I've understood it now.

Comment: returning a tuple is possible (at least in the latest version) see post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759483/how-to-return-two-values-in-cython-cdef-without-gil-nogil

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that cdef creates a function with a C signature and C call semantics. They cannot be called by Python. cpdef should be used to provide a Python wrapper around a cdef function.

Look it that way: cython is providing a bridge between C and python. cdef is the on the C end of the bridge. cpdef is on the Python end of the bridge.

There is a nice talk about [cython](http://www.behnel.de/cython200910/talk.html).

Comment: Actually, `def` is at the Python end. A `cpdef` is at *both* ends; both callable from Python and fast from C.