# How to return two values in cython cdef without gil (nogil)

Tags: python, cython

I have a function and I am trying to return a number and a vector of ints. What I have is

```
cdef func() nogil:
    cdef vector[int] vect
    cdef int a_number
    ...
    return a_number, vect
```

but this will give errors like `Assignment of Python object not allowed without gil`. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 13):

Cython has a `ctuple` type http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types

```
%%cython -a -f -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef (vector[int], double) func() nogil:
    cdef vector[int] vec
    cdef double d = 3.14
    cdef int i
    for i in range(10):
        vec.push_back(i)
    return vec, d
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a C++ structure: a struct, a vector, an std::pair, etc, not a python tuple object.

Comment: Could you provide a quick example on this? Thanks!!